# How to access a 'Delete Post' button within an array to delete user post

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql

I've used jQuery to post an array of User Posts to their profile page. In the array I've added a delete button to each post. I'm having trouble naming each button to coordinate it with the specific post of the user so I can delete the right post when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(show_user_tweets);  
function show_user_tweets() {
    var url = "controller.php";
    var query = { page: 'Profile', command: 'ShowUserTweets'};
    $.post(url, query, 
        function(data) {
            var rows = JSON.parse(data);
            if(rows.length > 0) {
                var t = "<table class='table table-borderless'>";
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    t += "<tr><td>"  
                    t += "<div class='modal-content'>";
                    t += "<div class='modal-header'>";
                    t += "<h2 class='modal-title'>" + rows[i]['Username'] + "</h2></div>";
                    t += "<div class='modal-body'>";
                    t += "<div class='form-group'>" + rows[i]['Tweet'] + "</div></div>";
                    t += "<div class='modal-footer justify-content-between'>";
                    t += "<div class='form-group'>" + "<input type='button' id='deleteBtn' name='rows[i]['UserId']' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'></input>" + "</div>";
                    t += "<div class='form-group'>" + rows[i]['Date'] + "</div></div>";
                    t += "</div></div></td></tr>";
                }
                t += '</table>';
                $('#pane-result').html(t); 
            }
        });
}
```

I currently have each button like: `<input type='button' id='deleteBtn' name='rows[i]['UserId']' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger'></input>`

How would I go abouts having each button tied to each specific post, so I can access it in my controller to delete from the SQL database?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have a repeated button id: `id=deleteBtn` (this repeat for each element of the data).

Change to `class` and add `data-id='rows[i]['UserId']'` to delete the selected post.

Use `data()` to capture the id to delete.

[Jquery .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Thank you! However, since I'm using bootstrap, my button class is btn. Can I change that to `class='deleteBtn btn btn-danger'` ?

Comment: Yes, you can change it. I suppose you listen the click event with `$(staticAncestor).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(e){...})`.